# Cannot redirect STDOUT to /home/ubuntu/workspace/shared/log/puma.stdout.log (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I have this error when I try to start my rails server. Before I pulled from the repo I am working from, I had no problems with running the server. I am using C9 IDE, but I don't think that's the issue.

```
[1708] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[1708] * Version 3.8.2 (ruby 2.3.0-p0), codename: Sassy Salamander
[1708] * Min threads: 1, max threads: 6
[1708] * Environment: development
[1708] * Process workers: 4
[1708] * Phased restart available
[1708] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:8080
[1708] Use Ctrl-C to stop
Exiting
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/runner.rb:111:in `redirect_io': Cannot redirect STDOUT to /home/ubuntu/workspace/shared/log/puma.stdout.log (RuntimeError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:45:in `redirect_io'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/cluster.rb:435:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/launcher.rb:172:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/rack/handler/puma.rb:64:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:297:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:104:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in server'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/spring:13:in `require'
    from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to create *shared* folder in *workspace*. Then create *log* folder in shared